# How to use URL patterns in a HTML file using Django?

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates, django-urls

I am creating a web application in Django, and I need to link to a webpage that creates a model and then redirects you back.

I have already created this webpage, but I need to create a link to it. This is the URL pattern for it (yes, it is long and ugly):

`path('add_to_trip/<int:id>/<str:name>/<str:addr>/<str:rating>', add_to_trip, name="add_to_trip"),`

I am trying to use this link to redirect to it, but Django can't understand it.

`<a class="btn btn-primary" href="{% url 'add_to_trip/{{trip_id}}/{{place_results_name}}/{{place_results_addr}}/{{place_results_rating}}' %}" style="margin-top: 10px;">Add to trip</a>`

This is the error I am getting:

`NoReverseMatch at /plan/3/ Reverse for 'add_to_trip/{{trip_id}}/{{place_results_name}}/{{place_results_addr}}/{{place_results_rating}}' not found. 'add_to_trip/{{trip_id}}/{{place_results_name}}/{{place_results_addr}}/{{place_results_rating}}' is not a valid view function or pattern name.`

I don't know why Django isn't using the URl pattern I provided.

Comment: Why you are not using `url` tag?

Comment: @SunderamDubey he actually is trying, but in a wrong way.

Comment: @SunderamDubey yeah, phone isn't the best tool for all the details. Thank you, sir :)

Answer (score 1):

For that url:

```
path('add_to_trip/<int:id>/<str:name>/<str:addr>/<str:rating>', add_to_trip, name="add_to_trip"),
```

You should use such syntax:

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="{% url 'add_to_trip' id=trip_id name=place_results_name addr=place_results_addr rating=place_results_rating %}" style="margin-top: 10px;">Add to trip</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

When using the url template tag, you only need to include the view name and any arguments separated by commas, without enclosing them in double curly braces.

Try this:

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="{% url 'add_to_trip' trip_id place_results_name place_results_addr place_results_rating %}" style="margin-top: 10px;">Add to trip</a>
```